# Find all ordered pair of integers $(x,y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Obtain all ordered pair of integers $(x,y)$ such that $$x(x + 1) = y(y + 1)(y + 2)(y + 3)$$

I'm getting 8,

(0, 0), (0, -1), (0, -2), (0, -3)
(-1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (-1, -3)

Please confirm my answer.

Comment: Thank you sir Andre, sir Marvis and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** It is easily proved that the product of four consecutive integers, plus $1$, is a perfect square. But $x(x+1)+1$ is hardly ever a perfect square!

**Added:** To prove that $y(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)+1$ is a perfect square, note that 
$$y(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)=y(y+3)(y+1)(y+2)=(y^2+3y)(y^2+3y+2)=z(z+2),$$
where $z=y^2+3y$. And clearly $z(z+2)+1=(z+1)^2$.

Comment: I can think of a couple of easy cases

Comment: @Henry: Thanks, I had made not a good choice of words.

Comment: x = 0, -1 are the only cases when x(x+1)+1 is a perfect square, right sir?

Comment: I'm getting 4 ordered pairs namely, (0,0), (0, -1), (0, -2), (0, -3).

Please confirm my answer.

Comment: You mentioned $x=-1$ above, but then forgot about it.

Comment: Sorry sir @AndréNicolas

I'm getting 8, 

(0, 0), (0, -1), (0, -2), (0, -3)
(-1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (-1, -3)

Comment: @Bazinga: No problem! You know what's going on, that's what's important.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** Assume $x>0$. Then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155040/to-prove-perfect-square) question along with the fact that $$x^2 < x^2 + x + 1 < (x+1)^2$$ should do the job. Argue similarly for $x \leq 0$