# Proving any product of four consecutive integers is one less than a perfect square

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove that : Any product of four consecutive integers is one less than a
perfect square.

OK so I start with $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ which can be rewritten $n(n+3)(n+1)(n+2)$

After multiplying we get $(n^2 + 3n)(n^2 + 3n + 2)$

How do I proceed from here to end up with something squared $- 1$?

Comment: What's $(n^2 + 3n + 1)^2 -1$?

Comment: I understand that's the answer, but I am not understanding how we go from (n^2 + 3n)(n^2 + 3n + 2) to (n^2+3n+1)^2−1

Comment: You have a product of the form $a\cdot (a+2)$, that's $(a+1)^2 - 1$. Or, more generally, $a(a+2b) = (a+b)^2 - b^2$.

Comment: You go $+1-1$ and rearrange.

Comment: Let $m=n^2+3n$; then $$\left(n^2+3n\right)\left(n^2+3n+2\right)=m(m+2)=m^2+2m=(m+1)^2-1\;.$$ Any product of two integers that differ by $2$ is one less than a square. You could also let $m=n^2+3n+1$ and rewrite the product as $(m-1)(m+1)=m^2-1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the product of four consecutive positive integers plus one is a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155040/prove-that-the-product-of-four-consecutive-positive-integers-plus-one-is-a-perfe)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might note that for any $N$ at all, $$(N-1)(N+1) = N^2-1$$ and so is one less than a perfect square. I presume you have seen this before.

Then you could take $N = M+1$ in the formula above, and get $$M\cdot(M+2) = (M+1)^2 - 1$$ is one less than a perfect square.

And here you have $M = n^2+3n$, don't you?

Answer (score 10):

Here's another approach you might use, a sort of brute-force approach.  You said you got as far as $$(n^2 + 3n)(n^2 + 3n + 2).$$  Continuing to multiply, you get: $$ n^4 + 6n^3 + 11n^2 + 6n.$$
The claim is that that this is one less than a perfect square, or equivalently, that $$n^4 + 6n^3 + 11n^2 + 6n + 1$$ is a perfect square.  If this last expression is a perfect square, it must be the square of something of the form $n^2 + an+b$ for some $a$ and $b$.  But what are $a$ and $b$?

Squaring $n^2 + an+b$, we get $$n^4 + 2an^3 +(a^2+2b)n^2 + (2ab)n + b^2$$

and equating the coefficients of the two polynomials we get $$\begin{align}
2a & = 6 \\
a^2+2b & = 11\\
2ab & = 6 \\
b^2 & = 1
\end{align}$$

which we can easily solve to obtain $a=3, b=1$.  So putting together the various steps we have $$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = (n^2 + 3n + 1)^2 - 1$$ which is what we were looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Observe that the product $p$ of four consecutive integers can be written as $p=(x-\frac{3}{2})(x-\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{3}{2})$ where $x=n+\frac{1}{2}$ for some integer $n$. Then $p=(x^2-\frac{9}{4})(x^2-\frac{1}{4}) = (x^2-\frac{5}{4}+1)(x^2-\frac{5}{4}-1) = (x^2-\frac{5}{4})^2-1$. It remains to show that $x^2-\frac{5}{4}$ is an integer, which is an easy bit of arithmetic.

Comment: That is a pretty cool approach! Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Well you can write the equation as this
$$(n^2+3n)(n^2+3n+2)=(n^2+3n+1-1)(n^2+3n+1+1)=(n^2+3n+1)^2-1^2$$
If you know you have to make this equation into an perfect square you need to get 2 same things and -1

Answer (score 1):

let the nos be 
n-1, n, n+1, n+2

we need to prove that (n-1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)+1= square no.
rearranging it : (n-1)(n+2)(n)(n+1)+1= square no.

LHS= (n-1)(n+2)(n)(n+1)+1
   =(n^2+n-2)(n^2 +n)+1
   = (k-2)(k) + 1                    (by replacing (n^2 +n) by k)
   =  k^2 -2k +1
   = (k-1)^2 
 hence proved , LHS is a square no.

on an interesting note,
(k-1)^2 = (n^2 +n-1)^2= {(n)(n+1)-1} ^2
therefore, the no. formed is always the square of, product of the two middle terms -1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the way to attack this that doesn't require guessing is this:  Start with $N (N-1) (N-2) (N-3) = N^4 - 6 N^3 + 11 N^2 - 6 N = M^2 - 1$  Since the product is "near" $N^4$, $M$ has to be "near" $N^2$.  And it's very likely that $M$ is a polynomial in $N$.  So set $M = N^2 + aN + b$.  Then $M^2-1 = N^4 + 2aN^3 + (2b+a^2)N^2 + 2abN + (b^2-1)$.  Setting that into the first equation and equating powers of $N$ gives $2a = -6, 2b+a^2 = 11, 2ab = -6, b^2-1 = 0$, which has the unique solution $a = -3, b = 1$.  So $M = N^2 - 3N + 1$ and $N (N-1) (N-2) (N-3) = (N^2 - 3N + 1)^2 -1$.