# How to solve $(x-2)^4+(x-3)^4=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying my hand on these types of expressions. how to solve $x$ and $y$ in $\displaystyle(x-2)^4+(x-3)^4=1$    and   $\displaystyle (y-1)(y-2)(y-3)(y-4)=1$?
   please write step by step solution !  thank u

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For the first case set $$z=\frac{x-2+x-3}2\iff 2z=2x-5$$

$$2^4=(2x-4)^2+(2x-6)^2=(z+1)^4+(z-1)^4=2\left(z^4+1+\binom42z^2\right)$$

Rearrange to form a Quadratic Equation in $z^2$

For the second set $\displaystyle a=\frac{y-1+y-2+y-3+y-4}4$

Comment: what is z and a here? and please explain more!

Comment: @user139567, See the definition of $z$ at the first line

Comment: ok but i dont understand why did u write that ??!

Comment: @user139567, obsrev that in either cases, I've replaced with the mean of the terms; it will eliminate the terms containing odd degree of $z$ and $a$ respectively

Comment: sorry but im not good at english .can u explain clearly please !

Comment: @jackcall, Please proceed with the suggested transformation and let me know if you are stuck

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

case 1: $2$ and $3$ are obvious solutions. Divide the polynom by $(x-2)(x-3)$ and solve the result.

case 2: $(y-1)(y-2)(y-3)(y-4) = [(y^2−5y)+5]^2−1$ [see this post about (y-1)(y-2)(y-3)(y-4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532737/proving-any-product-of-four-consecutive-integers-is-one-less-than-a-perfect-squa)