# How Product of four is $1$ less average of product's squared?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

How do I prove that product of $4$ consecutive integers is equal to 1 less than squared of the average of the product of last and middle terms ?

Ex: let $a,b,c,d$ be $4$ consecutive integers, then:
$$abcd= \left( \dfrac{ad+bc}{2} \right)^{2}-1$$

I can do this just by supposing values of $a= some\ even /odd$ but I need to arrive at this by not in this way, please help.

I found something similar [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532737/proving-any-product-of-four-consecutive-integers-is-one-less-than-a-perfect-squa) but how to frame it in this way?

Comment: The question you link to just shows that $abcd$ is one less than a square.  You can follow the algebra to find what it is the square of, which shows what you are after.

Comment: Sorry actually I m new here so I have little problem in formatting. But I will improve it.

Comment: @RossMillikan that's what I can't do, need MSE help.

Comment: The critical idea is using the fact that $a,b,c,d$ are consecutive, which is where replacing them with $x+1,x+2,x+3,x+4$ comes from.  Having done that, Kanwaljit Singh's solution is expanding the polynomials.  Look at each step carefully and make sure you understand that it works.

Comment: I tried to frame that with more explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let numbers are x, x+1, x+2, x+3.

Then Left side,

x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)

$=x(x+3)(x+1)(x+2)$

$= (x^2+3x)(x^2+3x+2)$

Put x^2+3 = Z.

$= Z(Z+2) = Z^2+2$

Now right side

$= \left(\frac{(x)(x+3)+(x+1)(x+3)}{2}\right)^{2} - 1$

$= \left(\frac{(x^2+3x)+(x^2+3x+2)}{2}\right)^{2} - 1$

$= \left(\frac{(Z)+(Z+2)}{2}\right)^{2} - 1$

$= \left(\frac{2Z+2}{2}\right)^{2} - 1$

$= (Z+1)^2 - 1$

$= Z^2+2Z+1-1$

$= Z^2+2Z$

Comment: You are going the wrong way, starting with what you want to prove.  All your steps are reversible, but it would be better to list them in the reverse order.

Comment: @RossMillikan yes, I need some different way of proof.

Comment: @Ayushakj:  you can just read up from the bottom with $a=x+1$ up to $d=x+4$

Comment: @RossMillikan but how can someone know to start from: $(x^4 + 10x^3+35x^2+50x+24)$

Comment: He is clever.  I would do what is shown here to find the answer, then present it by going down the left and up the right to go from start to finish.