# Prove that product of four consecutive natural numbers can not be a perfect cube

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is

> Prove that product of four consecutive natural numbers can not be a perfect cube .

I really dont know what actually do to proceed with the question. However after seeing this related result for the product of four consecutive numbers [Proving any product of four consecutive integers is one less than a perfect square](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532737/663538)
I tried with the same procedure of converting the product into a whole cube with a sum or difference of a constant . But i fail to do so. Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thank you

Edit: I just came to know the catalan's conjecture , so please if anyone could provide a proof for it or use some algebra to prove the question would be a great help.Also i think the question would not hold a very tough or lengthy proof since it is from a book recommended for students preparing for olympiads.

Comment: This is implied by "no number one less than a perfect square is a perfect cube" because of your link, right? In that case it's a corollary of Catalan's conjecture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture

Comment: at most two will have factor of 3.

Comment: Yes but the link was just for any help or idea

Comment: @79037662 i see that but do you have any other proof using algebra

Comment: @79037662 In fact the unique solution in positive integers to $y^3= x^2-1$ being $x=3,y=2$ goes back to Levi ben Gershon in 1343

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: but one of those multiples of 3 can be a multiple of 9, so that doesn't help.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for that, do you happen to know Levi ben Gershon's proof? If so (and if the proof isn't too long/hard), you can pretty easily write the answer to this question.

Comment: Think of $$n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$$

prime $p(>3)$ can divide exactly one of the multiplicands

So, if $n>1$ at least three of them will have distinct prim factors

Comment: @79037662 I may have got this backwards: he in fact showed that the only solutions to $2^n-3^m=\pm1$ are $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(3,4)$ and $(8,9)$

Comment: You get a near miss for $35\cdot 36\cdot 37\cdot 38 = 121^3-1$.

Comment: If $n$ is not divisible by $3$ you can easily show that $n(n+2)=(n+1)^2-1$ and $(n+1)(n+3)=(n+2)^2-1$ have no prime factors in common and would both have to be cubes. But they are too close together to be successive cubes. I can't though see a similar way to do the divisible by $3$ case - I'm trying to avoid appealing to other theorems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note if a prime $p>3$ divides one of the numbers, it can't divide any other. So it must occur cubed, in the form $p^{3k}$ for some $k$.

Second, note that at least one of the four numbers must be co-prime to both $2$ and $3$; so this number contains only primes $p>3$, and it must therefore be a perfect cube.

And if one of the numbers is a perfect cube, then the product of the other three must also be a perfect cube. So now we have reduced the problem to showing that the product of three out of four consecutive numbers can't be a perfect cube.

There are three cases: $n(n+1)(n+2), n(n+1)(n+3),$ and $n(n+2)(n+3)$. We show by elementary algebra that each of these lies strictly between two consecutive cubes, except for $n(n+1)(n+3)=8$ when $n=1$; so none of them can be a perfect cube, except for this one case. But this case does not lead to a counter-example of the full statement, because the missing number $n+2=3$ is not a perfect cube.

**Case 1**: $n(n+1)(n+2)$

$n^3<n(n+1)(n+2)=n^3+3n^2+2n<n^3+3n^2+3n+1=(n+1)^3$

**Case 2**: $n(n+1)(n+3)$

$n(n+1)(n+3)-(n+1)^3=n^2-1$, so unless $n=1$, we have $(n+1)^3<n(n+1)(n+3)<(n+2)^3$.

**Case 3**: $n(n+2)(n+3)$

$(n+1)^3=n^3+3n^2+3n+1\underset{3n<2n^2+5}{<}n^3+5n^2+6=n(n+2)(n+3)\underset{n(n+3)<(n+2)^2}{<}(n+2)^3$

Comment: Nicely done - you also could have $n$ as the cube but $(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ can't be a cube either because you've already proved that the product of three successive integers can't be. This is the proof I was fishing for ...

Answer (score 1):

Assume for a contradiction that $n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$ is a cube, where $n$ is a positive integer; of course $n\gt1$ since $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4=24$ is not a cube.

Of the two middle factors $n+1$ and $n+2$, whichever one is odd is relatively prime to the other three factors, so it is a cube, and the product of the three remaining factors is a cube; i.e., either $n(n+1)(n+3)$ or $n(n+2)(n+3)$ must be a cube.

But you can easily verify that, since $n\gt1$,
$$(n+1)^3\lt n(n+1)(n+3)\lt n(n+2)(n+3)\lt(n+2)^3.$$
Since there are no cubes between $(n+1)^3$ and $(n+2)^3$, we have arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: This is a distinct improvement on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, by generalizing the methods used in the previous two answers, it can be proved that product of $4$ consecutive positive integers can not be a perfect power (exponent $\geq 2$).

For the $4$ positive integers namely $x,x+1,x+2,x+3$, $x+1$ is coprime with the other three when $2|x$ while $x+2$ is coprime with the other three when $2\nmid x$. Assume for some $m,n\geq 2$, $x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)=m^n$. Notice that $m^n=(x^2+5x+5)^2-1$, we have $n\neq 2$, i.e. $n\geq 3$.

(1) If $2|x$, $\operatorname{gcd}(x+1,x(x+2)(x+3))=1$ and thus there exists $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $x+1=a^n,x^3+5x^2+6x=x(x+2)(x+3)=b^n$. However, as $x\geq 1$, $$(a^3)^n=(x+1)^3<x^3+5x^2+6x<(x+1)^3+2(x+1)^2\\<a^{3n}+2a^{2n}+1<a^{3n}+na^{3(n-1)}+1\leq (a^3+1)^n$$, drawing a contradiction.

(2) If $2\nmid x$, $\operatorname{gcd}(x+2,x(x+1)(x+3))=1$ and thus there exists $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ such that $x+2=a^n,x^3+4x^2+3x=x(x+1)(x+3)=b^n$. However, as $x\geq 1$, $$(a^3-1)^n\leq a^{3n}-a^{3(n-3)}(3a^{6}-2a^3+1)<a^{3n}-a^{3(n-3)}(2a^{6}+a^3)\\\leq a^{3n}-2a^{2n}-a^{n}+2=x^3+4x^2+3x<(x+2)^3=(a^3)^n$$, drawing a contradiction.

*Remark.* The inequality $(a^3-1)^n\leq a^{3n}-a^{3(n-3)}(3a^{6}-2a^3+1)$ follows from $(a^{3})^n-(a^3-1)^n\geq (a^{3})^{n-1}+(a^{3})^{n-2}(a^3-1)+(a^{3})^{n-3}(a^3-1)^2$.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so let's see , I am taking a bit different approach here :
n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)
For the above equation if we try to write the whole equation in the form of a single factor , (n+1) we can rewrite it as ,
(n+1)^4 + 2(n+1)^3 - (n+1)^2 - 2(n+1)
Now replacing (n+1) by t(where t is a natural number) we get ,
t^4 + 2 t^3 - t^2 - 2t

One taking factors common ,
(t^2 - 1)(t^2 + 2t)
=(t^2 - 1)[(t + 1)^2 - 1 ]

For this factor to be a cube root let's assume it to equal to p^3 (where p is a natural number).

Now by observation we can see that t^2 -1 < (t+1)^2 -1 , so the on comparing we can easily state that ,
(t^2 - 1) = p  and  (t+1)^2 - 1 = p^2 ( p^2 > p for any natural number)
Putting the original values again we get ,

(a) (n+1)^2 - 1 = p , which is not satisfied by any natural number values of n and p respectively .

(b) (n+2)^2 -1 = p^2 ,  which is again not satisfied by any natural number values of n and p respectively , which contradicts aur assumption.

Hence , it is proved that it cannot be a perfect cube.

Comment: It's not possible to assume that the factorization of $p^3$ is $p\cdot p^2$ unless $p$ is prime.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "*we can easily state that*" $\;-\;$ No, that does not follow. Just because a product of two different numbers is a perfect cube $ab=p^3$ does not mean that the two numbers must be $p$ and $p^2$. Try for example $p=6$, $a=9$, $b=24$.