# Multiplication of $m$ consecutive integers which is $1$ less a square: unique when $m=4$?

Tags: polynomials, integers

I came across this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155040/prove-that-the-product-of-four-consecutive-positive-integers-plus-one-is-a-perfe) which says that multiplication of $4$ consecutive integers is $1$ less than a perfect square. And I played around with numbers and polynomials to see if this is only when we exactly take $4$ integers, to no avail.

I think it is then valid to ask if this is uniquely a property of $4$. I don't know how to approach this funny question. I appreciate any help and insights.

Comment: If it works for any $n$ consecutive numbers, it must work for both $n!$ and $(n+1)! \; \; , \; \;$ and this is rare.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you very much for the nice and useful information!

Comment: @WillJagy The Brocard's problem seems to be a bit more restricted compared to my question. In my question for example $10\times11\times12\times13+1=131^2$ and any other "$4$" consecutive numbers can be chosen.