# Is there a product of $k$ consecutive integers which is one more (or less) than a perfect cube?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

I've seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155040/) with numerous proofs on the product of four consecutive integers being one less than a perfect square.

Then I've started to wonder: how many consecutive integers does one need to multiply in order to get a number one more or one less than a perfect **cube**? If it's not possible, I'd like to know a proof of that.

Comment: $18 \cdot 19 =342 = 341+1=7^3+1.$

Comment: @coffeemath is it generalizeable?

Comment: Please note that I did a typo. Should be $18\cdot 19 = 342 = 343-1= 7^3-1.$ My glaring error was to think 7^3=341. It's 343. I haven-t come up with say a one parameter family of such examples.

Comment: Found another: $36 \cdot 37 = 11^3+1.$

Comment: @Rusurano, $35 \cdot 36 \cdot 37 \cdot 38= 121^3-1$

Comment: A cube cannot be one more or one less than a product of _three_ consecutive positive integers since $(n-1)n(n+1)=n^3-n$ and for all $n>1$, $(n-1)^3+1<n^3-n<n^3-1$.